# How does the fieldIndex method work in a Spark SQL Row object?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

While I was looking at the [code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.scala) for `Row`, I came across these,

```
def schema: StructType = null

def fieldIndex(name: String): Int = {
  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("fieldIndex on a Row without schema is undefined.")
}
```

which doesn't look like much of a code for doing what they're supposed to be doing. So I was wondering how did they actually work? Maybe the actual definition is defined somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If subclass of the `Row` has a schema then this method is simply overridden. For example in a [`GenericRowWithSchema`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d83c2f9f0b08d6d5d369d9fae04cdb15448e7f0d/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/rows.scala#L213):

```
def fieldIndex(name: String): Int = schema.fieldIndex(name)
```

Comment: What about the `schema` function?